# How can I configure netcat (or some other stock linux utility) to listen on a specific port on a secondary IP address?

Tags: linux, centos5, netcat

CentOS 5.9

For testing purposes, I want my CentOS server to listen on a secondary virtual IP (eth0:0).  I'm familiar with `nc -l -p <port>` but it only listens on the primary. Is there a way I can specify a specific IP for the listener to use?

If not, is there another "stock" utility in CentOS 5.9 that can do this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The syntax depends on the `netcat` package.

**netcat-openbsd:**

```bash
# General form
nc -l ip port 
# Example
nc -l 192.168.2.1 3000
```

**netcat-traditional:**

```bash
# General form
nc -l -p port -s ip
# Example
nc -l -p 3000 -s 192.168.2.1
```

A simple way (at least in bash) for telling them apart in scripts is:

```bash
if ldd $(type -P nc) | grep -q libbsd; then
    nc -l 192.168.2.1 3000
else
    nc -l -p 3000 -s 192.168.2.1
fi
```

You can also run this one-liner to check manually:

```bash
if ldd $(type -P nc) | grep -q libbsd; then echo "netcat-openbsd"; else echo "netcat-traditional"; fi
```

Example output will be `netcat-traditional` or `netcat-openbsd`.

Comment: This is exactly what the man page says.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am not sure whether I understand correctly what you mean.

Comment: I think in netcat-traditional you can do `-l -p`

Comment: It means you will get lots of upvotes. :)

Comment: (*sigh) Thanks @HaukeLaging. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I guess I will take quite a while yet until I understand the practice rules of upvoting. If I have a look at what I get upvotes for (and much worse: What not for!) then I could cry. But it looks like this big problem's solution kicks me above the desired 3,000 points... (I noticed that on Unix & Linux my interest in rep dropped a lot after that)

Comment: This answer is incorrect, I don't know if this was ok in the past but now @schlicht's answer  is correct.

Comment: @SAMPro The answer was not incorrect but incomplete.

Answer (score 10):

To be complete, this command should work too:

```bash
nc -l -p port -s ip

# Example
nc -l -p 3000 -s 192.168.2.1
```

It works with `nc6` version 1.0 and `netcat` (The GNU Netcat) 0.7.1.

The [command from @Hauke Laging](https://serverfault.com/a/512337/357116) doesn't work with `nc6` (used in Debian).

Comment: The only way I can get to specify the listening interface on Ubuntu's `nc`.

Comment: nc says that you cannot use both -s and -l together

Comment: @SunSparc yet it is the only way to go for me to specify both local ip and local port in server mode - no other combination of options works here (nc v1.10-38, debian)

Comment: I think the issue could be that different netcat versions behave differently. I can't seem to get a version string out of mine, but there are at least two packages netcat-traditional vs netcat-openbsd.
`netcat -vvlp 4445 -s 172.17.0.1` gives me 
`listening on [172.17.0.1] 4445 ...`
vs 
`netcat -vvl 172.17.0.1 4445` gives me 
`listening on [any] 36539 ...`

Comment: I had to specify the -s flag on debian buster.

Answer (score 1):

### General netcat (`nc`) usage instructions, including setting the IP address to bind to when receiving, or to send to when sending

This one-liner ([modified from @Hauke Laging's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/512337/357116)), shows that I have the *netcat-openbsd* type on Ubuntu 22.04:

```bash
if ldd $(type -P nc) | grep -q libbsd; then echo "netcat-openbsd"; else echo "netcat-traditional"; fi
```

My output is:

> netcat-openbsd

The other type, per Hauke's wording, would be *netcat-traditional*.

Looking at the very bottom of `man nc`, I can also see that I have the BSD type:

> `BSD      March 31, 2021      BSD`

With this version of `netcat` (also callable as `nc`), here are the various ways to specify the IP address when both listening and sending.

Note that in all examples, you might instead call the "IP" or "IP Address" simply the "host", regardless of whether it is sending or receiving. In this way, each connected process is a "host".

### General netcat listening commands using *netcat-openbsd*

To listen, use `-l` in all of the commands. Note that he `-s` argument specifies the *source* IP address, and this command style works when *listening* only.

```bash
# -------
# TCP
# - withOUT `-u`
# -------

# General form 1 (netcat-openbsd only)
# - see Hauke's answer: https://serverfault.com/a/512337/357116
nc -l <ip> <port>
# example
nc -l 127.0.0.1 30000

# General form 2 (netcat-traditional-style)
# - see @schlicht's answer: https://serverfault.com/a/765633/357116
nc -l -s <ip> -p <port>
# example
nc -l -s 127.0.0.1 -p 30000

# -------
# UDP
# - just add `-u` to all commands above
# -------

# General form 1 (netcat-openbsd only)
# - see Hauke's answer: https://serverfault.com/a/512337/357116
nc -lu <ip> <port>
# example
nc -lu 127.0.0.1 30000

# General form 2 (netcat-traditional-style)
# - see @schlicht's answer: https://serverfault.com/a/765633/357116
nc -lu -s <ip> -p <port>
# example
nc -lu -s 127.0.0.1 -p 30000
```

**To bind to and listen to [`INADDR_ANY`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html), which means "any interface host IP address"**, you can use IP address `0`, like this:

```bash
nc -l 0 30000
# OR
nc -l -s 0 -p 30000
```

Or, even better, just omit the IP address entirely to bind to and listen on `INADDR_ANY`, like this:

```bash
nc -l 30000
# OR
nc -l -p 30000
```

### General netcat sending commands using *netcat-openbsd*

To send, just remove the `-l` from all commands. Note that the `-s` argument specifies the *source* IP address, and this command style works when *listening* only.

```bash
# -------
# TCP
# - withOUT `-u`
# -------

# General form (netcat-openbsd only)
# - see Hauke's answer: https://serverfault.com/a/512337/357116
nc <ip> <port>
# example
nc 127.0.0.1 30000

# -------
# UDP
# - just add `-u` to all commands above
# -------

# General form (netcat-openbsd only)
# - see Hauke's answer: https://serverfault.com/a/512337/357116
nc -u <ip> <port>
# example
nc -u 127.0.0.1 30000
```

To **send a particular binary file,** use `< filename.bin` at the end.

Example: send `filename.bin` as a UDP packet on IP address `127.0.0.1` (the inter-process-communication (IPC) loopback interface) port `30000`:

```bash
nc -u 127.0.0.1 30000 < filename.bin
```

Note that `filename.bin` in this example contains a binary, packed C struct data message with some variables in it, just as if you were writing a C program to send a struct as a UDP packet. See how it is generated in C, [in the bottom of my answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/707065/114401).

To send to [`INADDR_ANY`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html), which means "any IP address on any interface", you can use IP address `0`, like this:

```bash
nc 0 30000
```

### Interactive examples

##### Basic TCP/IP single listener (server), single sender (client)

1. In one terminal, start a TCP/IP listener (`-l`) ("server") on your local loopback interface (IP `127.0.0.1`), port `30000`:

   ```bash
   nc -l 127.0.0.1 30000
   ```
2. In another terminal, start an interactive TCP/IP sender ("client") to send to the same IP and port:

   ```bash
   nc 127.0.0.1 30000
   ```

   Now, type `hey`, and press Enter. You'll see it echoed in the sender's terminal, and received and printed in the listener's terminal. You can type more messages, pressing Enter after each one to send it. It's like a one-way chat program.

##### UDP single listener (server), multiple senders (clients)

1. In one terminal, start a UDP (`-u`) listener (`-l`) ("server") on your local loopback interface (IP `127.0.0.1`), port `30000`. Pass `-k` to enable it to receive from multiple senders by listening again after each receive:

   ```bash
   nc -luk 127.0.0.1 30000
   ```
2. In a second terminal, start an interactive UDP (`-u`) sender ("client"):

   ```bash
   nc -u 127.0.0.1 30000
   ```
3. In a third terminal, start another interactive UDP (`-u`) sender ("client"):

   ```bash
   nc -u 127.0.0.1 30000
   ```
4. You can now type repeatedly into either of the sender terminals above, and the listener will print out what it receives from either of the senders.

### Proof that IP address `0`, or `0.0.0.0`, is `INADDR_ANY`, and binds to all interfaces (all interface host IP addresss):

Run `ifconfig` to see all of your *interfaces* and their corresponding IP addresses. I have two interfaces:

1. `lo`, which is my virtual local "loopback" interface, with IP address `127.0.0.1`, and
2. `wlp0s20f3`, which is my wireless card, with IP address `192.168.0.67`.

We will use those in the commands below:

##### Basic TCP/IP single listener (server) bound to `INADDR_ANY` (all interfaces), with sender (client) sending to IP (host) `127.0.0.1` OR `192.168.0.67`

In this example, we'll listen and bind to `INADDR_ANY`, and see that a sender sending to either of my valid interface host IP addresses (`127.0.0.1` or `192.168.0.67`, as shown by `ifconfig`) can successfully connect to and send to this listener.

1. In one terminal, start a TCP/IP listener (`-l`) on `INADDR_ANY` (IP address `0`) and port `30000`:

   ```bash
   nc -l 0 30000
   ```
2. In a second terminal, start an interactive TCP/IP sender ("client") to your local loopback IP address of `127.0.0.1`, and port `30000`:

   ```bash
   nc 127.0.0.1 30000
   ```

   Now type `hello`, and press Enter. It works! The listener receives the data even when the sender sends to IP address `127.0.0.1`. This is because the listener is bound to `INADDR_ANY`, meaning it is listening on all interfaces, on each respective IP address for that interface, as shown by `ifconfig`.
3. Now kill both processes with Ctrl + C (note: if you kill just the sender, it kills both processes at once), and restart the listener in terminal 1:

   ```bash
   nc -l 0 30000
   ```
4. In the second terminal, start the sender again, but this time sending data to your external wireless *interface* at its host IP address of `192.168.0.67`, as previously shown by `ifconfig` above:

   ```bash
   nc 192.168.0.67 30000
   ```

   Type a word and press Enter, and again, the receiver will receive it, since it is listening on *all* of your active interfaces, as shown by `ifconfig`, since it is bound to host IP address `0`, which is the same as `0.0.0.0`, which represents `INADDR_ANY`, by common convention.

*It is important to note here that even though we are binding our listener above to `INADDR_ANY` (all interfaces), this does *not* mean it can have multiple connections at once! It is still *unicast*, meaning: a 1-to-1 relationship. It's just that it is bound to and listening on all interfaces, so a client can connect to this server listener on any of my two interface host IP addresses as shown by `ifconfig`, rather than just via one single interface host IP address that I would otherwise have to specify, choosing between any available interface host IP addresses shown by `ifconfig`.*

##### Basic TCP/IP single listener (server) bound to interface host IP address `127.0.0.1`, with sender (client) sending to `INADDR_ANY` (all interfaces)

In this example, we'll do the reverse of the previous example. We will bind to and listen on a specific interface host IP address, and show that a sender connecting to and sending to `INADDR_ANY` (all interfaces) can still reach this listener.

1. In one terminal, start a TCP/IP listener (`-l`) on interface host IP address `127.0.0.1` port `30000`:

   ```bash
   nc -l 127.0.0.1 30000
   ```
2. In a second terminal, start an interactive TCP/IP sender ("client") to `INADDR_ANY` (all interfaces, as represented by interface host IP address `0`, or `0.0.0.0`), and port `30000`:

   ```bash
   nc 0 30000
   # Or
   nc 0.0.0.0 30000
   ```

   Now type `hello`, and press Enter. It works! The listener receives the data even when the sender sends to `INADDR_ANY` (all interfaces) instead of to interface host IP address `127.0.0.1`.

Note that if I listen on interface host IP address `192.168.0.62`, which is my other interface's host IP address, as shown by `ifconfig`, for some reason the above does *not* work. I don't know why. Maybe it's a bug in `netcat`.

*Again, it is important to recognize here that even though we are sending to `INADDR_ANY` (all interface host IP addresses), this does *not* mean we can have multiple connections at once! It is still *unicast*, meaning: a 1-to-1 relationship. The TCP/IP sender will connect to the first TCP/IP listener it can, and just send to that one connection point, keeping that connection alive. UDP will do the same, acting as *unicast* and sending to a single UDP listener at a time, except that unlike TCP/IP, it does not *connect*, nor does it keep any connection alive. It just fires and forgets the data, and moves on.*

I don't know how the resolving is done as to *which* receiver will get the data if multiple receivers are listening on the same interface host IP address and port at the same time.

### See also

1. For more on this, and to see how to generate a binary `filename.bin` packet from a packed `struct` in C, see my Q&A here: ["Connection refused" when I try to send a UDP packet with netcat on an embedded-linux board](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/707065/114401).
2. See also my [git & Linux cmds, help, tips & tricks - Gabriel.txt](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/git%20%26%20Linux%20cmds%2C%20help%2C%20tips%20%26%20tricks%20-%20Gabriel.txt) notes document in my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) repo. Search it for `netcat`, `nc`, and `socat`.